# VBA - Why VBA UDFs are so slow compared with native Excel functions?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

let's suppose I write the following VBA UDF:

```
Function TestFunction()
    TestFunction = 0
End Function
```

and then I use it for the first 100000 rows in my sheet. It takes several minutes to execute.

Instead if i use TODAY() for the same number of rows it takes just 3-4 seconds to execute.

Can anyone tell me why and if is there a way to speed up UDFs?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it would be more instructional if you were able to show the actual slow function. VBA functions can be very fast but you do need to take care to make them fast (turn off automatic calculation while their executing, using arrays instead of manipulating cells directly..etc)

Comment: The answer is basically "because native is native, and VBA isn't".

Answer (score 5):

Several reasons.

VBA functions need to run sequentially, off the UI/main thread, and the compiled p-code needs to be interpreted by the VBA runtime.

Native functions are *native*. They're (presumably - AFAIK they're written in C++) already compiled to machine code that's readily executable and doesn't need to be recompiled and/or interpreted. Some native functions can also leverage multithreaded and "background" computing.

As for speeding up your UDFs, we'd need to see your UDFs for that. A function that does nothing other than assigning a literal return value, doesn't have much room for optimization does it?

UDFs are great. But they're not a silver bullet. If I wanted to write the value `0` to `A1:A1000000`, I'd do `Sheet1.Range("A1:A1000000").Value = 0` and that would be near-instant.

Consider looking into macros rather than UDFs if you're going to have hundreds of thousands of them to calculate.

Comment: Yes, I figured that the need for VBA code to be interpreted was the real issue. Thank u very much for your support!

Comment: Don't you think perhaps the interop is actually the main culprit in simple functions like the example? That is - a UDF requires reading/writing to the sheet 10,000 times rather than once as with a macro, and that's the majority of the reason it's slow, not because of multithreading or compiled vs interpreted code. Quite a tricky thing to time I imagine, but I just have a feeling the overhead in calling a function is more significant than the actual execution time of the code it contains (or doesn't, in this case!).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different reasons for this.

For one VBA UDFs are interpreted whereas native Excel worksheet functions are compiled. You would get big speed increases if you compiled your VBA code as VB6 for example. VBA and VB6 code are either the same or almost exactly the same. So the reason for the big speed increase would just be that the VB6 code is compiled rather than interpreted like VBA code is.

VBA code also doesn't produce the same type of worksheet functions that Excel does. VBA UDFs lack worksheet intellisense for example. You can't get this in any way through VBA. You can get it through external add-ins elsewhere however (e.g. Excel DNA.)

Another reason is that VBA isn't the best API for writing performant UDFs. That would be the C API. But the C API is harder to write UDFs in than in VBA.

There are also a number of other things that could affect speed, like your underlying hardware, or the algorithm you're using in the UDF. It's hard to give you useful suggestions without seeing your code.

Are you sure you need UDFs? The only advantages UDFs have over macros (that I'm aware of anyway) is that they don't delete the undostack after they're called whereas most macros do. And they can recalculate dynamically whereas you continuously have to rerun macros after they're called (unless you're using a worksheet event or something.)

If you're doing a ton of calculations on a range of cells, it's probably better to just write the range to an array, manipulate it in VBA, and then just write it back to the range.

Comment: Erm... No VBA isn't interpreted, it's compiled to `PCode` which is then interpreted at runtime. Formulas are still interpreted too, but may indeed be linked to compiled C functions.

Comment: @Sancarn Compiled typically means that it's compiled into something like an EXE or a DLL, which VBA code never is. My statement was based on [this comment](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CreatingCOMAddIn.aspx) from Chip Pearson: "Performance -- A CAI is an ActiveX DLL that is compiled into native machine code. A CAI runs considerably faster than the interpreted code of VBA."